# CSS textbox focus

Tags: html, css

I am trying to disable/remove the border or the blue glow in the text box.

```
.user {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(222,222,222,.0);
    border: 2px solid rgba(222,222,222,0);
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-family: arial;
    margin-bottom: -8px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.user::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #ffffff;
}

.password {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    border: #e9e9e9;
    background-color: rgba(222,222,222,.0);
    border: 2px solid rgba(222,222,222,0);
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-family: arial;
    margin-top: -8px;
}

.password::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #ffffff;
}
```

The form part:

```
<form method="post" class="login_form">
    <div style="font-size: 20px; font-family: bebasregular; text-align: right; color: #ffffff;">Login</div>
    <input type="text" name="user" class="user" id="user" placeholder="Username or Email"/>
    <hr/>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="password" placeholder="Password"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="login_btn" class="login_btn" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

Now, what I'm trying to make is that the two text boxes in the form will become transparent, even they're in focus.

i tried this code below, but it doesn't work.

```
.user{
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(222,222,222,.0);
    border: 2px solid rgba(222,222,222,0);
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-family: arial;
    margin-bottom: -8px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.user:focus{
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(222,222,222,.0);
    border: 2px solid rgba(222,222,222,0);
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-family: arial;
    margin-bottom: -8px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.user::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #ffffff;
}

.password {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    border: #e9e9e9;
    background-color: rgba(222,222,222,.0);
    border: 2px solid rgba(222,222,222,0);
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-family: arial;
    margin-top: -8px;
}

.password:focus {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    border: #e9e9e9;
    background-color: rgba(222,222,222,.0);
    border: 2px solid rgba(222,222,222,0);
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-family: arial;
    margin-top: -8px;
}

.password::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Try to put it "outline: none;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove this by adding: `outline: none;` to the .`user` class (or any element that may receive the outline):

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnoj3qcx/)

***Sidenote:***
I think its worth noting that on your `hover` states, you only need to specify the properties that change on that that state. For instance, if the element text color is white initially, and you want it to still be white on hovered state, you can omit that on the `hover` state.

Comment: thank you so much. you are life saver ^_^ i've been trying to recoding the css for about 3 hours long lol but now my problem has been solved. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The bluish glow is coming from the default outline styles. To remove it try:

```
input { 
    outline: none;
}
```

This will remove it from the user, password, and when the button is pressed.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/btggdt6k/)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
input { 
    outline: none;
}
```

or change

```
border: 2px solid rgba(222,222,222,0);
```

to

```
border: 0px;
```